# How to check if Tensorflow is using the CPU with the C++ API?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

I have a C++ program using Tensorflow 2 to run inferences of a convolutional neural network. The program runs on a server with a dedicated GPU and the expected behavior is the inference to run on the GPU. In case of a GPU failure, Tensorflow starts using the CPU instead of the GPU. Is there any way with the Tensorflow C++ API to check if Tensorflow is using the CPU? Is there any way with the C++ API to avoid Tensorflow switching to the CPU in case of GPU failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved it in the following way:

```
bool DedicatedGPUAvailable(tensorflow::Session* session){
    if (session != nullptr) {
        std::vector<tensorflow::DeviceAttributes> response;
        session->ListDevices(&response);

        // If a single device is found, we assume that it's the CPU. 
        // You can check that name if you want to make sure that this is the case
        if (response.size() == 1) {
            std::cout << "No GPU found! Total available devices = 1" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Available devices: " << std::endl;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < response.size(); ++i) {
                std::cout << i << " " << response[i].name() << std::endl;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```